# How to plot my json data into a Google Material Line Chart using PHP, MySQL, & JavaScript

Tags: php, json, charts, google-visualization, linechart

Good day!
My code doesn't display the chart.
I am trying to plot my json data into a google material line chart to output a chart like these: [image]

here's my javascript code:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['line', 'corechart', 'bar','controls', 'table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartCountry);

function drawChartCountry() {

    var jsonData1 = $.ajax({
        url: "analytics/country-sales.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData1);

    var options = {
    title: 'Top 20 Countries with the highest sales',
    pointSize: 5
    };
    var formatter_amount1 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: 'HKD ', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true});
   // formatter_amount1.format(data1, 1);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_country'));
    chart.draw(data1, options);

}
```

and here's my json data

```
    {"cols":[[[{"label":"Date","type":"string"},{"label":"TAIWAN","type":"string"},{"label":"HONG KONG","type":"string"},{"label":"JAPAN","type":"string"},{"label":"INDONESIA","type":"string"},{"label":"THAILAND","type":"string"},{"label":"UNITED STATES","type":"string"},{"label":"PHILIPPINES","type":"string"},{"label":"UNITED KINGDOM","type":"string"},{"label":"MALAYSIA","type":"string"},{"label":"AUSTRALIA","type":"string"},{"label":"SINGAPORE","type":"string"},{"label":"SPAIN","type":"string"},{"label":"SWEDEN","type":"string"},{"label":"GERMANY","type":"string"},{"label":"VIET NAM","type":"string"},{"label":"SOUTH KOREA","type":"string"},{"label":"NORWAY","type":"string"},{"label":"FRANCE","type":"string"},{"label":"CANADA","type":"string"},{"label":"NETHERLANDS","type":"string"}]]],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,1)"},{"v":48876},{"v":3970},{"v":2505},{"v":1824},{"v":982},{"v":676},{"v":491},{"v":387},{"v":238},{"v":173},{"v":162},{"v":108},{"v":101},{"v":98},{"v":96},{"v":91},{"v":88},{"v":84},{"v":82},{"v":72}]}]}
```

here's the html code (removed some elements not related to this topic)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="analytics/sales-country.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div id='chart_div_country' style='width: 100%; height: 600px;'></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me please. Thank you.
any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue with the snippet you shared? Seems OK to me.. Can you pinpoint the exact issue faced by you?

Comment: the chart is not displaying :(

Comment: Can you also post your html? What you have shown is the logic, which seems fine, but your presentation is not working, so we should the also look at the view definition (your html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**first**, the `"cols"` are wrapped in too many arrays

`[[[]]]` vs. `[]`

`{"cols":[[[{"label":"Date","type":"string"},...,{}]]],`

should be...

`{"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"string"},...,{}],`

**next**, the column type for the line series should be `'number'`
and recommend `'date'` for the first column

this...

```
  "cols": [
    {"label":"Date","type":"date"},
    {"label":"TAIWAN","type":"number"},
    {"label":"HONG KONG","type":"number"},
```

*not* this...

```
  "cols": [
    {"label":"Date","type":"string"},
    {"label":"TAIWAN","type":"string"},
    {"label":"HONG KONG","type":"string"},
```

**also**, if you want a *Material* line chart,

just need the `'line'` package and...

`google.charts.Line`

the *Core* chart version is...

`google.visualization.LineChart`

**and highly recommend** not using `async: false`, use `.done` and `.fail` callbacks instead

see following working snippet, move code from `.fail` to `.done` to test locally...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  callback: drawChartCountry,
  packages: ["line", "corechart"]
});

function drawChartCountry() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "analytics/country-sales.php",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    var jsonData = {
      "cols": [
        {"label":"Date","type":"date"},
        {"label":"TAIWAN","type":"number"},
        {"label":"HONG KONG","type":"number"},
        {"label":"JAPAN","type":"number"},
        {"label":"INDONESIA","type":"number"},
        {"label":"THAILAND","type":"number"},
        {"label":"UNITED STATES","type":"number"},
        {"label":"PHILIPPINES","type":"number"},
        {"label":"UNITED KINGDOM","type":"number"},
        {"label":"MALAYSIA","type":"number"},
        {"label":"AUSTRALIA","type":"number"},
        {"label":"SINGAPORE","type":"number"},
        {"label":"SPAIN","type":"number"},
        {"label":"SWEDEN","type":"number"},
        {"label":"GERMANY","type":"number"},
        {"label":"VIET NAM","type":"number"},
        {"label":"SOUTH KOREA","type":"number"},
        {"label":"NORWAY","type":"number"},
        {"label":"FRANCE","type":"number"},
        {"label":"CANADA","type":"number"},
        {"label":"NETHERLANDS","type":"number"}
      ],
      "rows":[
        {"c":[
          {"v":"Date(2014,1,1)"},
          {"v":48876},
          {"v":3970},
          {"v":2505},
          {"v":1824},
          {"v":982},
          {"v":676},
          {"v":491},
          {"v":387},
          {"v":238},
          {"v":173},
          {"v":162},
          {"v":108},
          {"v":101},
          {"v":98},
          {"v":96},
          {"v":91},
          {"v":88},
          {"v":84},
          {"v":82},
          {"v":72}
        ]},
        {"c":[
          {"v":"Date(2015,1,1)"},
          {"v":48876},
          {"v":3970},
          {"v":2505},
          {"v":1824},
          {"v":982},
          {"v":676},
          {"v":491},
          {"v":387},
          {"v":238},
          {"v":173},
          {"v":162},
          {"v":108},
          {"v":101},
          {"v":98},
          {"v":96},
          {"v":91},
          {"v":88},
          {"v":84},
          {"v":82},
          {"v":72}
        ]}
      ]
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
      title: 'Top 20 Countries with the highest sales',
      pointSize: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div_country'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    //console.log('error', textStatus);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div id='chart_div_country' style='width: 100%; height: 600px;'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, if you want to see an actual line, you'll also need more than one row in the `data`...

Comment: hellow WhiteHat, Thank you so much for this answer. thank you! thank You. this really helped me.